# Using Ajax to send a var to a query

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, ajax

I am using a POST to grab data from an on click event using angularjs. I think I have most of the code written but I am getting 'Invalid Character' error when I run the query. I think it may have something to do with the type conversion when I grab the variable from javascript.

this is my post for my java file

```
@POST
@Path("module")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ModuleProcCount> getInput(int jobId) throws IOException{
    try (Dbc dbc = vehmPool.getDbc()){
        List<ModuleProcCount> pusher = statements.inMod(dbc, jobId);
        return pusher;
    } 
}
```

Here the function or my post

```
$scope.sendJobId = function(jobId) {    
        $http.post("rest/performance/module", jobId).then(function(response){
            $scope.pusher = response.data;

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.pusher.length; i++) {
                var p = $scope.puller[i];
                console.log("modName: " + p.modName);
                console.log("modClass: " + p.cellClass);
                console.log("modData: " + p.modCount);
        }
    });
```

Here is my HTML with the angular code in it.

```
<table id="Table" class="JobID-table" style="text-align:center" >
    <tr class="table-Header">
        <th>JOB ID</th>
        <th>TIME FOR ALL MODULES(MILLISECONDS)</th> 
    </tr>
    <tr class="jobID-Table-tr" ng-repeat="p in puller | orderBy : '-modCount'"> 
        <td ng-click="sendJobId(p.modName)" class={{p.cellClass}}>
        {{p.modName}}   
        </td>
        <td class={{p.cellClass}}>
        {{p.modCount}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java method is set to consume JSON (`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`). This means JAX-RS is trying to parse the body of your POST request into a JSON object then map it to the parameter type of your consumer function, in this case `String`.

Since you’re not  actually sending a JSON object with your POST request, you should tell JAX-RS that you want to receive the raw text from the payload:

```java
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
```

---

Alternatively, you could embrace the JSON! Since you mention your parameter is an integer, this example uses a JSON object with a single integer parameter called `jobId`:

```java
/**
 * This class is used by JAX-RS to parse to and from JSON. The field
 * names used here (and by extension the getters and setters) should
 * match those used in your JSON.
 */
class InputRequest {
    int jobId;

    public String getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }

    public void setJobId(int jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }
}

@POST
@Path("module")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<ModuleProcCount> getInput(InputRequest reqPayload) throws IOException {
    int jobId = reqPayload.getJobId();
}
```

On the client side, angular automatically converts an object passed for the payload to a JSON string and sets the `Content-type` header for you ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)).

```js
$http.post('rest/performance/module', {
  jobId: 123456
});
```

Comment: Could I do this with an int?

Comment: If you want automatic handling of data types in the payload, you should wrap it in a JSON object. I’ll add an example to my answer,